# The name Savechanges() dies not exist in the current context in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am migrating my code from EF to EF Core.
We do have an Igenericreposirory.
And this Igenericreposirory is inheriting by Genericreposirory.

IGenericreposirory

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataLayer.Repositories.Base
{
public interface IGenericRepository<T, TKey> where T : class
{
       T Add(T entity);
}
}
```

GenericRepository:

```
public class GeneralRepository<T, TKey> : IGenericRepository<T, TKey>
    where T : class, IEntity<TKey>, new()
 {
    protected readonly DbContext DbContext;
    internal DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public GeneralRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");

        this.DbContext = dbContext;

        this.DbSet = this.DbContext.Set<T>();
    }

public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        #region Argument Validation

        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        #endregion

        var obj = DbSet.Add(entity);
        SaveChanges();
        return obj;
    }
```

}

Here I am getting 2 errors while working with EF core 
1 at return obj as "Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry' to 'T'"

2 at Savechange() as "the name savechanges()" does not exists in the current context.

As far as i know , EF core supports all methods to fetch , Insert, ADD

Comment: Please include more details about the error you get, including its line number. And consider including the scope of both the object/function you want to use and the scope where you're using it.

Comment: Hi Chase, I have updated the question . can you please check.

Comment: `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

Comment: In addition to @Backs SaveChanges is a method from an object, not a method from current class...

Comment: `this.DbContex.SaveChanges()` to be precise

Comment: Thank you, Everyone., How can we achieve AddorUpdate in  EF Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1 at return obj as "Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry' to 'T'"

The signature of `DbSet.Add()` has been changed between EF6 and EF core. In EF6 it returned the entity itself, see the documentation of [`DbSet.Add() in EF6`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.add?view=entity-framework-6.2.0):

> ```
> public virtual TEntity Add (TEntity entity);
> ```

But in EF core it has been changed to return an `EntityEntry` object instead, see the documentation of [`DbSet.Add() in EF core`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.add?view=efcore-3.1):

> ```
> public virtual Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<TEntity> Add (TEntity entity);
> ```

So you have to return the value of the [`EntityEntry.Entity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry-1.entity?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_EntityEntry_1_Entity) property to get the tracked entity (which might be the same as your `entity` variable). So the code might look like this:

```
var obj = DbSet.Add(entity);
// [...]
return obj.Entity;
```

### 2 at Savechange() as "the name savechanges()" does not exists in the current context.

Your are trying to call a method `SaveChanges();` on your class `GeneralRepository`, but there is no such method defined. However, the `DbContext` object has [such a method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). Simply call the method from your `DbContext` instead:

```
var obj = DbSet.Add(entity);
this.Context.SaveChanges();
return obj.Entity;
```

Comment: Thanks, program, I have posted one more question, can you please provide an answer for that.